# ValidateRequest stopped working after changing .net to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, validate-request

I get this error after changing from .Net 4.5 to 4

the error says:
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

In my 4.5 solution i have "ValidateRequest="false"" in the top of my aspx page. But that doesn't seem to work anymore.

I know why the error appears, but not how to make it disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this to your config file

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode%28VS.100%29.aspx